# Custom tcl environment

Tags: deployment, package, tcl

Is it possible to create an own tcl environment?

What basically want to have is an own executable of Tcl8.5 but with some of my own package embedded in it.

This would make it much easier to distribute a tcl application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. One of the standard ways to use Tcl is as an embedded language: you just link your code against the Tcl library and go from there.

If you want to make your code work like an extended version of `tclsh` then you just call [`Tcl_Main()`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Tcl_Main.htm) at the right point, with one of the arguments that you pass in being a callback that will add the local packages/commands that you want to add. It's conventional to call such a function [`Tcl_AppInit`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/AppInit.htm) but you can call it anything you want really.

Otherwise, you do things more manually.

```
// Initialize the Tcl library first
Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);

// Make the interpreter
Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

// Add your stuff in here

if (Tcl_EvalFile(interp, "your_main_script.tcl") != TCL_OK) {
    // IMPORTANT: If things go wrong, print what happened. Saves debugging time!
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp)));
    exit(1);
}

// Delete and clean up
Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
exit(0);
```

Comment: This looks great but I have one question. The in this example "your_main_script.tcl" is it needed after compilation or will it be embedded in the binary?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Tclkit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/52) and [Kitgen Build System](http://wiki.tcl.tk/18146) - these systems can build an all-in-one-file Tcl runtime, also you can customise what packages get included.